# Nullable Array and Why Do We Need Them

Tags: c#, arrays, nullable

I see code like this and I understand it as making an array nullable but I dont understand why do we need it since arrays are ref types, so they are already nullable.

So, my question is why do we need this?

```
private readonly decimal?[] _amounts = new decimal?[_count];
```

Comment: It looks like the main confusion here is that it is not a "nullable array of decimals", but "a regular array of nullable decimals".

Comment: Thanks, that explains it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's worth to mention that from C# 8.0 you can have a **nullable reference type**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types

but as others mentioned this:

```
private readonly decimal?[] _amounts = new decimal?[_count];
```

means the value-type elements in array can be null. `decimal` is value type and normally you can't assing null to it but if you have `decimal?` then you can.

With C# 8.0 and nullable reference types feature enabled you should declare reference types as nullable reference types if you want to assing null to them, otherwise you'll get compiler warning by default. You can declare one like this:

```
private decimal?[]? _amounts;
```

Now it means that both elements in array can be null and entire array (_amounts variable) may be null.

So in general the question mark after element value type `?` and before `[]` `->` `SomeValueType?[]` means that elements in array can be null. From C# 8.0 (with feature enabled in project) question mark `?` after array type `SomeArrayType[]` `->` `SomeArrayType[]?` means that you can assign null to variable that holds reference to the array.

Comment: Awesome explanation.  Much appreciated BART!

Comment: This explains how, while 'how' being useful to know,, it doesn't cover OP's question about 'why' you might need it

Answer (score 8):

Declaring it as `decimal?[]` means that the elements the array    contains **can be `null` or non-null**.

Without making it *nullable*, the elements the array can store    **cannot be `null`**.

In other words, `decimal?[]` reads as "an array of *nullable* decimals". The `?` is referring to the elements the array can contain and not the array itself as all arrays are reference types.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between the array object itself and the elements of the array. When you use `decimal?[]` you are declaring an array whose elements are nullable `decimal` values. If you were to use `decimal[]?` (I'm not sure that's valid syntax, but just for explanation purposes, assume it is) you would be declaring a variable that may refer to an array or may not refer to anything. The later is the useless case you describe because, like you say (at least in older versions of C#) all array variables are reference variables that can already be set to `null`.

To clarify the difference, consider the code posted by Alejandro, and also this code:

```
decimal[]? reallyNullable = null;

Array.Sort(reallyNullable); // ArgumentNullException -- there is no array here
Array.Sort(nullable); // OK, assuming null can be compared to decimal.
```

The reason the last line is OK is because there is actually an array object referenced here. The only thing that's null are some of the values in it.

Answer (score 1):

The nullable specifier here refers not to the array itself, but to the contents of it. As you correctly say, the array in itself is a reference type, and there fore, always nulable (at least until C#8).

A few examples of the difference:

```
decimal[] nonNullable = new decimal[2];
nonNullable[0] = 1;             //OK, a non null item
nonNullable[1] = null;          //Compile error: array doesn't accepts nulls
nonNullable = null;             //OK, set the array reference to null

decimal?[] nullable = new decimal?[2];
nullable[0] = 1;                //OK, a non null item
nullable[1] = null;             //OK, a null item (actually, a Nullable<decimal> instance)
nullable = null;                //OK, set the array reference to null
```

Comment: Please note my question initiates array as new decimal?[count], not new decimal[count]

Comment: @cd491415 Yes, I noted that. I put both for the sake of comparison to show in which cases they have different behavior, both your specific case and a made up one.